# How to escape string interpolation in snippet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets

String interpolation is great and snippets are great, but they don't play nice together. I have a snippet that looks (in part) like this:

```
job.Location = $"{e["$locationfield$"]}";
return true;
```

The `locationfield` part is supposed to be the replacement, but of course it will see as `'"{e["` being a replacement. So when you try to use the snippet, that part is messed up:

```
job.Location = locationfield
```

And the rest of the code following is gone (because it can't match another `$` presumably).

Is there a way around that? Or can you just not use string interpolation in your snippets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, as it turns out, it's dead simple. I did this on a whim and it worked:

```
job.Location = $$"{e["$locationfield$"]}";
return true;
```

Another solution that I didn't try, is that you can actually specify what the snippet should use as a delimiter:

```
<Code Language="csharp" Delimiter="$">
```

Just change the `$` to something else you *aren't* using in this particular block of code.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: I know, but not for 2 days. Which means I'll probably forget it altogether.